# Why would CREATE INDEX with "online" mode suddenly slow my database down?

Tags: index, azure-sql-database

Earlier I used `CREATE INDEX ... WITH(ONLINE=ON)` without any problems - the statement would run in parallel with user queries and not slow them down at any time. Then suddenly I see that once I start the statement the database slows down greatly - user queries pile up, usually with `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait mode and the database effectively becomes unusable until I cancel the statement. The slowdown begins immediately after I initiate the statement execution. It happens both when I try to create an index that differs from existing indices and when I try to create an index identical to one of existing indices (with a different name of course).

What could possibly cause such change?

Comment: ONLINE=ON still requires a lock at the end to replace the old index with the new one. This may be what you are running into. When you run with ONLINE=ON it is essentially re-creating the index from scratch in the tempdb then once complete dumping it from there over your old one. To do that it needs a (very temporary) lock.

Comment: Additionally the server still needs to read the data and write to tempdb, so will of course use IO, Processor, and memory to complete the activity. ONLINE=ON may still be a resource intensive operation but it allows you to avoid a lock for the duration of the index creation.

Comment: Some pageiolatch_sh wait is normal but sustained high values is a pretty good indicator you have buffer pool memory pressure,  (other causes are less common). That said, your question is somewhat vague. Do you mean 1) create index online ran fine for a while then you experience performance problems while the same task is still running or  2) create index online worked fine earlier but now causes perf issues with the same index  or  3) create index online worked fine for one index but causes perf issues with another index? They're different issues that can have different causes. Please clarify

Comment: @JoshSimar The slowdown starts immediately once the statement start running.

Comment: @SQLmojoe I added that into the question. The problem occurs both when creating an identical index and a non-identical index.

Answer (score 2):

The OIB is causing your DB to run over some SLO limit (most likely IO or Log IO), causing resource governor to kick in. See [Azure SQL Database resource limits](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-resource-limits/).

Comment: Why would this not happen earlier and what do I do to overcome it?

Comment: I can't know that, you should open a case and ask for assistance.

Comment: Won't tell you why but you can see which specific resources you're using up lots of by going to the portal, click on your database then click on the "edit" link in the Monitoring window of your database properties. That brings up a list of resources and time range you can select to monitor.

Comment: You can shout a help cry to https://twitter.com/azuresupport